# How to change accounts-facebook configuration using mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to change my accounts-facebook configuration in my database. When I type `db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.find()` I get my configuration credentials as follows:

```
{ "_id" : "fksgshdflgn", "service" : "facebook", "appId" : "24242", "secret" : "wlkjrowrw", "loginStyle" : "popup" }
{ "_id" : "sldjfiods", "service" : "google", "clientId" : "sladarpoigfd-somelink.apps.googleusercontent.com", "secret" : "lksodfisfsosdf", "loginStyle" : "popup" }
```

how do I change the `_id` and `secret` attributes of the Facebook login service?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using the following commands:

```
meteor mongo
```

then

```
db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.remove({_id: "facebookID"});
```

:)